# How to set up a custom ListView in a Fragment (Android)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-listview, android-xml

I have set up 3 swipe view tabs/screens and in one of them I want to display a custom ListView. For some reason, when I reach that particular tab, the app crashes. My code is as follows:

Snippet for the swipeview

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {


        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new SOA();
        case 1:
            return new tv();
        case 2:
            return new Onstage();

        }

        return null; }
```

Code for Onstage()  --- my class to setup the custom listview

```
public class Onstage extends Fragment {

ListView lv;
Context context;
Adapter adapter;

ArrayList prgmName;
public static String [] prgmNameList={"Arkham","Vendetta","Corleone"};
public static String [] prgmNameList2={"Arkham","Vendetta","Corleone};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scoreboard, container, false);

    lv=(ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.onstagelist);
    adapter=new Adapter(this, prgmNameList, prgmNameList2);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    return rootView;


}}
```

I cannot extend this to ListFragment because swipeview only accepts fragments (I think)

scoreboard.xml

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context="com.example.second.Onstage" >


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/onstagelist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Custom Adapter

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

String [] name;
String [] name2;
Context context;
int [] imgid;
private static LayoutInflater inf=null;

public Adapter(Onstage onstage, String[] prgmNameList, String[] prgmNameList2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    name=prgmNameList;
    this.context=context;
    name2=prgmNameList2;
     inf = ( LayoutInflater )context.
             getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return name.length;
}


@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}


public class Holder
{
    TextView tv1,tv2;

}




@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowview;
    rowview=inf.inflate(R.layout.scoreboard_layout, null);
    holder.tv1=(TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.eosname);
    holder.tv2=(TextView) rowview.findViewById(R.id.eosvenue);
  ``holder.tv1.setText(name[position]);
    holder.tv2.setText(name2[position]);
    return rowview;

}}
```

And scoreboard_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/eosname"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eosvenue"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />


</LinearLayout>
```

The Logcat is as follows:

```
02-22 10:46:04.316: D/AndroidRuntime(17969): Shutting down VM
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969): Process: com.example.second, PID: 17969
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at com.example.second.Adapter.<init>(Adapter.java:27)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at com.example.second.Onstage.onCreateView(Onstage.java:32)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:249)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5255)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
02-22 10:46:04.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
02-22 10:46:08.991: I/Process(17969): Sending signal. PID: 17969 SIG: 9
```

Comment: could you please send ur logcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** In the `onCreateView` of your `Onstage`, replace

```
lv=(ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.onstagelist);
```

with

```
lv=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.onstagelist);
```

The reason is that `getView()` cannot be called before `onCreateView()` returns, as the `View` returned by `getView()` is generated first by `onCreateView()`.

**2.** The second error that you have posted is occurring because your `context` reference is null. Your `Adapter`'s constructor

```
public Adapter(Onstage onstage, String[] prgmNameList, String[] prgmNameList2) {...}
```

does not have a `Context` parameter, so the line `this.context = context` fails to initialize the `context` field. Define the `Adapter` constructor as

```
public Adapter(Onstage onstage, String[] prgmNameList, String[] prgmNameList2, Context context) {...}
```

and pass a valid `context` instance to it (it should be an instance of `Activity`, so get it by calling `getActivity()`).

**3.** You can make `Onstage` a `ListFragment` and it will work.

Comment: It's still crashing. And when I extend it to ListFragment, it shows me an error because I'm asking for a fragment as a return in my swipeView snippet. I've also added the logcat of the errors.

Comment: It worked!
Thanks a lot ma'am. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @ZygoteInit Please, do you think you could give me some advice/ideas over here http://goo.gl/E37NSu

Comment: @eddy: interesting question ...... I provided an answer, hope you find it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

`ListFragment` extends `Fragment`, so yes, you can use it anywhere that a `Fragment` can be used. Your crash is here:

```
lv=(ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.onstagelist);
```

You're calling `getView()` from within `onCreateView()` -- you haven't yet returned the `View` so `getView()` does not have it. Either move that code to `onViewCreated()` or change it to look within your inflated view, i.e.:

```
lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.onstagelist);
```

Comment: It's still crashing. And when I extend it to ListFragment, it shows me an error because I'm asking for a fragment as a return in my swipeView snippet. I've also added the logcat of the errors.